# Magento connect manager is not present at the admin panel

Tags: magento2, magento-connect-manager

I've installed magento on my local server but the issue is that i don't see magento connect manager at the admin panel please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2 does not have the "Magento Connect Manager" anymore.

If you are looknig for the "Component Manager", find it at "System > Web Setup Wizard".

[image]

More info: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/compman-start.html

Comment: And how to install a package from a ZIP file (aka "Direct package file upload" in Magento v1.x)?